# Obtaining Left and Right Arrows As Plot Symbols in R

Tags: r, plot, symbols

I have a data set that I would like to plot in R that contains a factor with categories of "left" and "right". I'd like to use plot symbols that somehow indicate direction, with a simple solution being triangles that point left and right.  However, the standard symbol list in R only includes triangles that point up and down (pch = 2,6 or 24,25 for example, with a complete symbol list [here](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html)). What's the most straightforward method of plotting triangles that point left and right?

Note: I've tried using < and > from the ascii set (pch = 60 and 62), although I'd like symbols that have better visibility because I'll eventually be using these figures on a projector. I'll fall back on these symbols if there isn't a better solution.

Comment: There's an `arrow` function which you can use to draw.

Comment: you can use `pch=-8592` and `pch=-8594` (http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/arrows.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
plot(x=0, type="n")
text(1, .5, paste0("0.5", intToUtf8(9660)))
text(1, -.5, paste0("-0.5", intToUtf8(9650)))
```

[image]

Left: 9664, right: 9654

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using pch=-9658 and pch=-9668 because 9664 and 9654 wouldn't display properly, but this got me to the right solution.